# Multiple variables in one subscription

Tags: node-opcua

I've read that it is better practice to put multiple variables into one subscription compared to creating more subscriptions.

I'm using this example (https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua-htmlpanel) and want to read more variables in subscription.

My code responsible for reading one variable - one node.

```
const nodeIdToMonitor = 'ns=3;s="OP_UA_FB_DB"."OPC_Data"."Data_integer"';

const itemToMonitor = {
      nodeId: nodeIdToMonitor,
      attributeId: AttributeIds.Value,
    };
    const parameters = {
      samplingInterval: 100,
      discardOldest: true,
      queueSize: 100,
    };
    const monitoredItem = await subscription.monitor(
      itemToMonitor,
      parameters,
      TimestampsToReturn.Both
    );

    monitoredItem.on("changed", (dataValue) => {
      io.sockets.emit("message", {
        value: dataValue.value.value,
        timestamp: dataValue.serverTimestamp,
        nodeId: nodeIdToMonitor,
        browseName: "ISP",
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

To monitor multiple variables in one subscription you can make use of the `monitorItems` method call. This method call takes an array of nodes to be monitored as input and create monitored items for all the nodes present in the array.

Here is a sample code snippet that you can make use of to monitor multiple nodes,

```
const parameters1: MonitoringParametersOptions = {
    discardOldest: true,
    queueSize: 100,
    samplingInterval: 100,
    filter: new DataChangeFilter({
        deadbandType: DeadbandType.Absolute,
        deadbandValue: 0.1,
        trigger: DataChangeTrigger.StatusValueTimestamp,
    }),
};
const itemsToMonitor2: ReadValueIdOptions[] = [
{
    attributeId: AttributeIds.Value,
    nodeId: nodeIdToMonitor
},
{
    attributeId: AttributeIds.Value,
    nodeId: nodeIdToMonitor1
}];

const item2 = (await subscription.monitorItems(
    itemsToMonitor2,
    parameters1,
    TimestampsToReturn.Both))

// If a data change is detected print the value
item2.on("changed", (monitoredItem: ClientMonitoredItemBase, dataValue: DataValue, index: number) => {
    console.log("Index", index);
    console.log(" The value has changed : ", dataValue.toString());  
});
```

I see that you are using open source OPC UA implementations. Here are a list open source implementations that you might be interested in trying out:

- open62541 – https://open62541.org/certified-sdk.html – C stack | Mozilla License | Embedded ready | TSN ready
- NodeOPCUA – https://node-opcua.github.io/ – NodeJS | MIT License | Cloud ready
- FreeOpcUa – https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/freeopcua – C++ | LGPL-3.0 License | Python bindings
- UA .NET stack – https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard – RCL License for corporate members of OPC Foundation & GPL 2.0 for others | Standard profile | Web oriented implementation

If you are looking for more hands-on information, you can also check out these resources:

- Free documentation: You can look at the open source documentation page: https://open62541.org/doc/current/
- Paid online course: Practical introduction to OPC UA – code walk-through and examples in this course use the open62541 stack: https://opcfoundation.org/products/view/practical-introduction-to-opc-ua-part-i